# Is the design change on Chrome related to design changes on SE?

Tags: discussion

At the same time as I saw design changes to a beta SE site that I visit, I noticed the design of Google Chrome also changed and the changes in appearance were very similar.

Are these changes related and is there a fundamental alteration being experienced across the entire internet?

Answer (score 4):

Mandatory disclaimer: this is not an official answer by a Stack Exchange employee.

The changes you're seeing come from Google Chrome 71. While a lot of modern UX design follows the same guidelines, there's no direct relationship between the changes in SE and Chrome, and the fact that they were released on adjacent dates is purely coincidental.

Comment: The changes were visible in the Canary version before the first responsive site rolled out.

Comment: Plot twist: Spolsky owns Google ...